# How do I use a use a timer loop in JavaScript without freezing the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, loops, timer

I'm trying to learn how to dynamically change display in a browser using Javascript and CSS.  Everything has been going fine, until I tried looping a change. The code fires once and works fine, but when I try to loop it, every loop I try freezes the browser.  I'm obviously new to JavaScript, and doing something very wrong.  Here's the problem code:

```
function changes()
{
  var x = 0;  
  do
  {    
    setTimeout(timerRed, 3000);  
    setTimeout(timerWhite, 6000); 
    setTimeout(timerBlue, 9000);
    setTimeout(timerBlack, 12000);  
    setTimeout(timerGreen, 18000); 
    setTimeout(timerOrange, 21000);
    setTimeout(timerClear(x), 24000);  
  } while (x >= 0);  
}
```

I'll skip timerRed() etc... in the interest of saving space and because the CSS changes are working fine.  At the end of the cycle, I try this:

```
  function timerClear(x) 
  {
    clearTimeout(x); 
    x = 0; 
  }
```

And freeze the browser.  So, what is the **correct** way to loop these  functions.

Thank you

PS: In other words, I want to loop or cycle the color functions infinitely, without locking the browser.

Comment: Infinite loop... x is never < 0.

Comment: I have looked at other loop code and it did not apply to my situation.

Comment: But that's the catch, it should be an infinite loop.  I want the color cycling to continue until the browser closes.  So how do I cycle without locking the browser?

Comment: `setInterval(changes, 24000)`. (And lose the loop, as already mentioned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, GOT IT!!

```
  function changes()
  {
    color(); // changes() tests a lot of JavaScript CSS I've been trying out, but color() is the only thing relevant to my question, the rest would just be clutter.    
  }

  function color() 
  {
    setTimeout(timerRed, 0000);  
    setTimeout(timerWhite, 3000); 
    setTimeout(timerBlue, 6000);
    setTimeout(timerBlack, 9000);  
    setTimeout(timerGreen, 12000); 
    setTimeout(timerOrange, 15000);
    // And I create the infinite loop of color cycling with**out** locking up the browser by having color call itself at the end of every color cycle
    setTimeout(color, 18000);        
   }
```

Thank you, everyone, for your input.  Hopefully this will assist the next JavaScript newbie that runs into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding, but if you intend to have these timers firing forever, you should use an interval, which will keep firing until stopped:

```
function changes()
{ 
    setInterval(timerRed, 3000);  
    setInterval(timerWhite, 6000); 
    setInterval(timerBlue, 9000);
    setInterval(timerBlack, 12000);  
    setInterval(timerGreen, 18000); 
    setInterval(timerOrange, 21000);
}
```

If you ever need to stop one of these, create it like this:

```
var redInterval = setInterval(timerRed, 3000);
```

...and to stop it:

```
clearInterval(redInterval);
```

Comment: Well, that was a step in the right direction, thank you.  Only problem is, the functions are firing out of order.  Red, white. blue, black, red fires early, green, orange, black out of order, blue out of order, etc...

Comment: That is because they are each firing at different frequencies. To retain the same sequence, have the same number of milliseconds in all setInterval calls, with a wait between them.

Comment: Thank you weir.  What exactly is a "wait"? How would I code that?

Comment: What weir means is you have the red interval set to 3000 (3 seconds), the white 6000 (6 seconds), etc. Make them all the same, such as 3000, and they will all fire at the same time. Better yet, make just one interval and put all of the code inside that one function if you intend for all of them to fire at the same time. That makes no need for multiple instances "setInterval".

Answer (score 1):

Lose the do while loop. You are creating a bazillion of each of those timers, which in turn are firing each callback function a bazillion times. Also note that your local variable x is not in scope within the callbacks.

Comment: *"So, what is the correct way to loop these functions"* - You've only said what *not* to do... OP wants the code to loop forever (without freezing the browser).

Comment: `which in turn are firing` - none of them ever fire because the loop never exits

Comment: GOT IT!! I have to care for an ill loved one, then I'll post the code. Thank you everyone for your input.